# How can I show the progress of a Jface TableViewer Refresh when using a filter?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am adding a ViewerFilter to my TableViewer.

```java
ViewerFilter filter = new MyViewerFilter();   
this.tableViewer.addFilter(this.filter);
```

I am using the below code for filter and refresh of TableViewer

```java
this.filter.setSearchText("some text");   
this.tableViewer.refresh();
```

Since this is taking a long time (maybe around 5 secs), I want to show the progress of refresh using a progress monitor. However I am unable to find the  amount of refresh done to set work done in ProgressMonitor.worked() method.

Comment: Setting the table redraw off while the refresh is running might help a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API. The current API assumes that refresh is so fast that you wouldn't need this. You can try to optimize the filter code or make the table virtual. But my guess is that your table is simply too big. Find a way to reduce the size.